# Trouble web scraping data from a tag's inline style attribute

Tags: java, regex, web-scraping, jsoup

So I have a couple of spans with inline styles:

```
<span style="...;width:8px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:16px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:13px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:20px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:0px;..."></span> //width=0px
<span style="...;width:5px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:3px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:90px;..."></span>
<span style="...;width:200px;..."></span>
```

I want to extract the "px" value and store it into an array. When we hit a span with `width=0px`, that signifies the end of that array. So the above will look like this:

`array1 = [8, 16, 13, 20]`

`array2 = [5, 3, 90, 200]`

We can use an arraylist of integer arrays to store the data.

What I have so far is very basic: `Elements spanWidths= doc.select("span");`

So far this produces:
`"border:...;width:8px;..."`

I believe that we use regex to solve this but I'm not very accustomed to it. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex would be `\bwidth\s*:\s*(\d+)px`. Then take the value from the first capture group. That is, call `.group(1)` on the resulting match.